# Java Reading From JSON

Tags: java, rest

I am looking to get the weather from this weather API I am using in a Netbeans Java project into my own Maven API, this is all working fine but returning a huge chunky JSON response when I want to break it down into smaller readable text.

My code is currently returning:

> {"coord":{"lon":-6.26,"lat":53.35},"**weather**":[{"id":801,"**main**":"Clouds","description":"few
>   clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","**main**":{"**temp**":285.59,"pressure":1015,"humidity":58,"temp_min":285.15,"temp_max":286.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1539610200,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5237,"message":0.0027,"country":"IE","sunrise":1539586357,"sunset":1539624469},"id":2964574,"name":"Dublin","cod":200}

I would instead like it to be able to return, main in weather and temp in weather as well. If anyone has any ideas let me know. Code is attached.

```
public class WeatherInfo {
     public static String getWeather(String city) {
        String weather;
        String getUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ city +"&appid=xxx";
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource target = client.resource(getUrl);

        ClientResponse response = target.get(ClientResponse.class);
        weather = response.getEntity(String.class);
        return weather;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "main in weather and temp in weather as well"? Can you give desired json?

Comment: @noobCoder updated my JSON above and made bold what I want to be able to read/output, right now i'm able to view the main - temp using a json object for the main then a toDouble for the temp but I haven't been able to view the weather - main

Comment: ok, let me know if the answer I posted works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your desired return value from `getWeather` is `{"main":"Clouds","temp":285.59}`
Here is a solution for that - 
add jackson dependency in your pom

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is a method that strips out other details and returns only main and temp, you can edit this method to add more fields.

```
private static String getLessWeather(String weatherJson) throws IOException {
  Map<String, Object> lessWeatherMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
  Map<String,Object> weatherMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(weatherJson, LinkedHashMap.class);
  String main = (String) ((LinkedHashMap)((ArrayList)weatherMap.get("weather")).get(0)).get("main");
  lessWeatherMap.put("main", main);
  Double temp = (Double)((LinkedHashMap)weatherMap.get("main")).get("temp");
  lessWeatherMap.put("temp", temp);
  return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(lessWeatherMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library to parse the JSON response. Here is an SO question with great examples and references: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

The answer from user SDekov lists three good options:

- Google GSON
- Org.JSON
- Jackson